# how safe is it to install packages in legacy mode?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package, package.json

I need a graphics package to draw graphs.  I am using version react 18. When I install it says I need version 17 for this package.

can i install this package in legacy mode tell me cyber security is this correct? Or is it better not to? Or is it better to look for other graphic editors version 18?

if I install the package in legacy mode, will it be safe? or is it better to install packages only that are compatible with react 18

```
npm i legacy peer deps
```

I typed in the search how safe it is to install packages in legacy mode and did not find the answers

Comment: This package wasn't tested with react 18, so there is no way to know if it is going to work. It might, it might not, it might seem to work but cause bugs in some specific situations. It's up to you if you think this risk is acceptable

Comment: in terms of vulnerability and security?

Comment: Bugs may lead to security issues yes, again it's impossible to tell without testing